# Spring Integration MessagePublishingErrorHandler

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

Всем привет!
Столкнулся с проблемой `MessagePublishingErrorHandler`. Немного не понимаю, все ли верно происходит в каналах и обработке.

Есть следующий bean:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow compliteManualDealStatusFlow(CompleteDealStatusServise 
                                                              completeDealStatusService,
                                                    MessageChanel 
                                                          comleteManualDealStatusChannel, 
                                                    OutputManualModeServiseLogger 
                                                           outputManualModeServiseLogger, 
                                                    MessageChanel backtestDealChanel){                                                            
return IntegrationFlow
.from(completeDealStatusService)
.handel(completeDealStatusService)
.transform(outputManualModeServiseLogger)
.channel(backtestDealChanel)
.get();
}
```

Правильно ли я понимаю, как работает этот бин?
Сначала из канала `completeDealStatusService` мы забираем сообщение/объект, далее в `.handel(completeDealStatusService)` передаем и что-то делаем в данном методе, далее с вернувшимся объектом в `.transform(outputManualModeServiseLogger)` и в итоге отправляем в канал `backtestDealChanel`?

Теперь мне нужно из этого бина отправить в еще один метод мой объект, и я изменяю код следующим образом:

```
    @Bean
public IntegrationFlow compliteManualDealStatusFlow(CompleteDealStatusServise 
                                                              completeDealStatusService,
                                                    MessageChanel 
                                                          comleteManualDealStatusChannel, 
                                                    OutputManualModeServiseLogger 
                                                           outputManualModeServiseLogger, 
                                                    MessageChanel backtestDealChanel, 
                                                          CloningService cloningService){
return IntegrationFlow
.from(completeDealStatusService)
.handel(completeDealStatusService)
.handel(cloningService, "sendManualDeal")
.transform(outputManualModeServiseLogger)
.channel(backtestDealChanel)
.get();
}
```

В логах после этого я получаю ошибку `MessagePublishingErrorHandler`. Что я могу делать не так? В свяжи с чем происходит данная ошибка? Влияет ли расположение методов на данную ошибку?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Хорошо быд бы увидеть полный stacktrace ошибки, но виглядит так, что требование посылать рузультат `.handel(completeDealStatusService)` в `.handel(cloningService, "sendManualDeal")` и `.transform(outputManualModeServiseLogger)`. Для этого рекомендуется использовать `publishSubscribeChannel(Consumer<PublishSubscribeSpec> publishSubscribeChannelConfigurer)`:

```
.handel(completeDealStatusService)
.publishSubscribeChannel(pubSub - > pubSub.subscribe(subFlow -> subFlow..handel(cloningService, "sendManualDeal")))
.transform(outputManualModeServiseLogger)
.channel(backtestDealChanel)
```

Таким образом будет два подпищика на этот канал: врутренний `subscribe()` и следующий `transform()`.

Документация здесь: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-subflows

Если это не так, то дай, пожалуйста, больше информации о требованиях и об ошибке.

P.S.: Я предпочитаю отвечать на такие вопросы на английском.

Comment: Артем, спасибо! А может ли влиять что метод sendManualDeal не возвращает объект, он void?

Comment: Верно. Это одна и клачических проблем, когда мы не возвращаем никакой результат и сервиса, но ожидаем, что остаток логики будет выполнен. И как раз для таких случеав `PublishSubscribeChannel` подходит как нельзя лучше.

Comment: То есть в данному случае возвращать не обязательно объект? А дальше в transform он пройдет?

Comment: Правильно. Такова идея подхода я предлжил. Можно оставить так как есть, но тогда  `sendManualDeal()` должен возвращать то что он получил на вход.

Comment: Спасибо! Это отличный вариант. А такой вариант подошел бы?
.wireTap(sf -> sf.handel(cloningService, "sendManualDeal").nullChannel())

Comment: Да, такое тоже возможно, но не понятно зачем `nullChannel()`, если кузультат `void`...

Comment: Артем, почему-то не помогло ваше решение. Куда ещё можно капнуть?

Comment: Предоставленная ошибка не имеет отношения к коду ты показываешь. Также было бы хорошо вставлять ошибки в вопрос как кусок кода, чтобы нам было легче его читать. Похоже проблема с сущностью в теле сообщения которая пытаеться соедениться с ДБ через её HibernateProxy: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-proxy-to-real-entity-object